# Switching transistor off when current is supplied to it's base

Tags: transistors, switching

Is it possible to switch off a LED when current is applied to base of a transistor? I am using the circuit below but when current is applied to the base, the LED is ON. I need the LED to be off when SW1 is on. I am using 2N1613.

[image]

Comment: Are you limited to this particular circuit or can you use other components?

Comment: I can use any component. Transistors, gates just about anything.

Comment: Why is there the restriction that you must *apply* current to the base to switch the LED off? Couldn't this part of the circuit be changed?

Comment: Actually yes. I am open to any solution. I need to turn off the LED when there is power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the switch to shunt the base current away from the transistor:

[image: shunt base current]

If you really need to *apply* base current to switch the LED off, you could use the transistor to bypass the LED:

[image: shunt LED]

However, this wastes all of the current that normally goes through the LED. A more power-efficient circuit would use another transistor that gets its base current shunted away by the first transistor:

[image: two-transistor inverter]

Comment: Thank you! I think this will work for me. Can I use any NPN transistor?

Comment: Yes. (The 2N1613 and most other small-signal transistors have enough amplification to get away with less base current; you should be able to replace the 1K resistors with 10K.)

Comment: I just tested it and it worked beautifully. Now suppose I use 2 of this circuit, the other one with the polarity reversed, how do I keep LED1 glowing?

Comment: So you want to control two LEDs with one switch? That would be a different question.

Comment: Never mind, I got it working. Yes actually if I connect a LED between the R2 and the transistor connecting led- to ground, it works.

Comment: I used a 1K in place of 330 ohms for R1. Now if my entire circuit runs on 3V, should I have to lower the resistor values?

Comment: How to calculate resistors for a transistor's base or for a LED are different questions. A comment is not the appropriate place to ask them.

Comment: @CL. why 3rd one power efficient that 2nd one ?

Comment: @FastSnail The current through R1 is larger than that through R2 or R3.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about wasting power just put the transistor in parallel with the grounded LED. It will shunt the current away from the LED when the transistor is on, and turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is. here is how you do it: break between led- and collector of the npn; have led- connected to ground; connect led+ to collector. done. here is how it work. when sw1 is off, npn is off, collector voltage will be 6v, and so led is on. when sw1 is on, npn is on, collector voltage will be 0, and so led is off.